# where syntax error goes in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript

If I run this code in Firebug everything goes fine and works:

```
var ingarray =$(".ingsparts");

$.each(ingarray ,function(n){
var ing = ingarray[n];
console.log($(ing).find('.name').val());
console.log($(ing).find('.value').val())

});
```

but if I run this, it doesn't work:

```
var ingarray =$(".ingsparts");

$.each(ingarray ,function(n){
var ing = ingarray[n];
var in = $(ing).find('.name').val();
var ms = $(ing).find('.value').val();

});
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work

Comment: What about providing the actual error message? ;-)

Comment: thanks all. i forget that In is reserved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `in` is a reserved word; use another variable name.

Comment: Yes indeed, `in` is an operator. For a full list of reserved words, see Section 7.6.1 of [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Answer (score 3):

`in` is a reserved word in Javascript ([see here for more info](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6557)), you will have to rename this variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, dont use in as variable name, but also, your each can be done more simply:

```
var ingarray = $(".ingsparts");

ingarray.each(function(){
  var name = $(this).find('.name').val();
  var value = $(this).find('.value').val();
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The second example defines the in and ms variables inside the function. This means that they get function scope and are not usable outside of the function. So the variables are set, but never used and not accessed.